# changing the color of an ellipse using hashtag data using Twitter4j 3.0.3

Tags: java, twitter, colors, processing, twitter4j

Okay, so i dont really know much about writing code, yet. I am working on a project that uses twitter API data. My goal for the project is to use hash tags to represent both good and bad things (for sake of simplicity, lets use #good and #bad).

I want that hashtag data to modify the color of a simple ellipse to a shade of color in between red and green, depending on the number of #good and #bad tweets.
I like to think of it as a +100/-100 spectrum. each #good tweet is +1, each #bad is -1. If it is at -100 tweets, then the ellipse is full red. If it is at +100 tweets, then the ellipse is full green.

I know this is a little complicated, but its for an art project im doing. I followed a tutorial and currently have the twitter data responding on a simple array list of tweets (tutorial @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwS6irtGK-c)
I am using processing, java, twitter4j 3.0.3, and a macbook pro with OSX el capitan 10.11.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even pointing me in the direction on how to code it myself. If you need more information from me, ill respond as quickly as I see it!

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
Twitter twitterInstance;
Query queryForTwitter;

ArrayList tweets;

void setup() {
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("****");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("****");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("****");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("****");
  cb.setUseSSL(true);
  twitterInstance = new TwitterFactory( cb.build()
                                  ).getInstance();
  queryForTwitter = new Query("#good");

  size(640,440);
  FetchTweets();

} //setup

void draw() {
  background(0);
  DrawTweets();
} //draw

void DrawTweets() {
  for(int i=0; i<tweets.size(); i++) {
    Status t = (Status) tweets.get(i);
    String user = t.getUser().getName();
    String msg = t.getText();
    text(user + ": " + msg,
         20,15+i*30-mouseY, width-20, 40);
  } //for
} //drawTweets

void FetchTweets(){
  try {
    QueryResult result = twitterInstance.search(
                                queryForTwitter );
    tweets = (ArrayList) result.getTweets();
  } catch(TwitterException te) {
    println("Couldn't connect: " +te);
  } // end of catch TwitterException
}// end of FetchAndDrawTweets()
```

SECOND VERSION:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
Twitter twitterInstance;
Query queryForTwitter;

//ArrayList tweets;

void setup() {
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("****");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("****");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("****");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("****");
  cb.setUseSSL(true);
  //twitterInstance = new TwitterFactory( cb.build()
  //                                ).getInstance();
  //queryForTwitter = new Query("#feelthebern");

  size(640,440);

   int numGood = 50;
   int numBad = 50;
  for (int i = 0; i < numGood; i++) {
    tweets.add("#good");
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < numBad; i++) {
    tweets.add("#bad");
  }

} //setup

ArrayList<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();



//create a function that counts the tweets
//that contain a certain hashtag
int countTweets(String hashtag){
  int total = 0;
  for(String tweet : tweets){
    if(tweet.contains(hashtag)){
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

void draw(){

  //count the good and bad tweets
  int goodTweets = countTweets("#good");
  int badTweets = countTweets("#bad");

  //calculate color based on tweet counts
  float r = badTweets/100.0 * 255;
  float g = goodTweets/100.0 * 255;
  float b = 0;

  background(r, g, b);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to break your problem down into smaller steps.

**Step 1:** Create a function that simply returns an `ArrayList` of tweets.

**Step 2:** Create a function that takes that `ArrayList` and a `String` value, and returns the number of times that `String` occurs in the tweets in the `ArrayList`.

This code assumes you have a `ArrayList<String> tweets`:

```
int countTweets(String hashtag){
  int total = 0;
  for(String tweet : tweets){
    if(tweet.contains(hashtag)){
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```

**Step 3:** Calculate the color based on the number of tweets containing each word. You said you'll always have 100 tweets, so you can just divide the tweet count by 100, then multiply by 255 to get the color value.

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
ArrayList<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();

void setup() {

  //you would actually get these from twitter,
  //but for testing let's just fill them ourselves
  int numGood = 50;
  int numBad = 50;
  for (int i = 0; i < numGood; i++) {
    tweets.add("#good");
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < numBad; i++) {
    tweets.add("#bad");
  }
}

//create a function that counts the tweets
//that contain a certain hashtag
int countTweets(String hashtag){
  int total = 0;
  for(String tweet : tweets){
    if(tweet.contains(hashtag)){
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

void draw(){

  //count the good and bad tweets
  int goodTweets = countTweets("#good");
  int badTweets = countTweets("#bad");

  //calculate color based on tweet counts
  float r = badTweets/100.0 * 255;
  float g = goodTweets/100.0 * 255;
  float b = 0;

  background(r, g, b);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. It seems to work, As it is a green background on my end currently. One question, you said "you would actually get these from twitter, but for testing lets just fill them ourselves."
Im not sure i understand that completely. Thanks again for working with me, sorry im a noobie!

Comment: @zack.gray.ou No problem. With that comment, I just meant that in your real program, you're connecting to twitter to get the tweets, but just for my small example I'm manually filling htem up with either `"#good"` or `"#bad`", since you aren't really asking about the twitter part of the problem.

Comment: Oh, I understand now! 

I did, however, come across another problem. I assumed my code was correctly working, but I ran a println and it seems that its not actually collecting hashtag data. I could be wrong, but it looks like its just repeatedly running 50 "#good" and 50 "#bad" at any given time...
I added the new code to the main question above under "second version"

Comment: @zack.gray.ou You shouldn't be using the code I have in my `setup()` function. That was only for testing purposes. That's what my comment meant.You should be populating your `ArrayLists` with tweets, not hardcoded `Strings`. I just used hardcoded `Strings` to demonstrate the code for iterating over them to count the number of good and bad. Your real code should use data from twitter, not hardcoded `Strings`.

Comment: ah. i wish i could run this all by my professor, but he cant get back to me. im very confused on all of this now. i thought i knew what i was doing but i guess i do not as well as i thought.
Okay, so in Step One of your original answer is basically what I have in the first code in my question? Im sorry to be so difficult. I am just so lost. My professor was originally supposed to guide me through this, as I am new to processing and programming, but as I mentioned hes not helping at all at this point...

Comment: @zack.gray.ou You would need to write a function that returns an `ArrayList` of `Strings` that you get from twitter. You have 90% of this function written already, so I didn't bother including it in my example. Instead, I just used hardcoded `Strings` to show you the part you were having trouble with: iterating over the `Strings` to count the number of times `"#good"` or `"#bad"` occur.

Comment: okay so I have been trying this whole time to get the stupid function to work but i just cant do it. my professor still cannot meet with me. Once i get this code working I still have a lot more to do with it after, but i think i can get that going by myself.
So ive been messing with the "function that counts the tweets that contain a certain hashtag." do i need to mess with the setup too?? im sorry to keep bugging you. im just really stressing about maybe having to drop this class.