# java 8 syntax conversion for processing 2 (twitter4j)

Tags: java, java-8, processing, twitter4j

I was informed that this code will not work in processing because it is java 8 syntax, which is not supported in processing. I need help converting it to work in processing. What syntax can Processing 2 handle? Is there a way to convert the java 8 syntax to work within Processing 2?

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws TwitterException {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline("google");
    String hashtag = "#AlphaGo";
    System.out.println("The Twitter page contains " 
                        + countTweets(hashtag, statuses) 
                        + " tweets with the hashtag : " + hashtag);

}

public static int countTweets(String hashtag, List<Status> statuses){
    return (int) statuses.stream()
                         .filter(x -> x.getText().contains(hashtag))
                         .count();
}
```

Since Im having problems with declaring variables:
CURRENT VERSION

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
Twitter twitterInstance;
Query queryForTwitter;
ArrayList<Status> tweets = new ArrayList<Status>();

//ArrayList tweets;

void setup() {
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxx");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxx");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xxx");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxx");
  cb.setUseSSL(true);

  size(640,440);

int countTweets(ArrayList<Status> statuses, String hashtag){
  int total = 0;
  for(Status tweet : statuses){
    if(tweet.getText().contains(hashtag)){
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

   int numGood = 50;
   int numBad = 50;
  for (int i = 0; i < numGood; i++) {
    tweets.add("#good");
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < numBad; i++) {
    tweets.add("#bad");
  }

} //setup

//create a function that counts the tweets
//that contain a certain hashtag
int countTweets(String hashtag){
  int total = 0;
  for(String tweet : tweets){
    if(tweet.contains(hashtag)){
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

void draw(){

  //count the good and bad tweets
  int goodTweets = countTweets("#good");
  int badTweets = countTweets("#bad");

  //calculate color based on tweet counts
  float r = badTweets/100.0 * 255;
  float g = goodTweets/100.0 * 255;
  float b = 0;

  background(r, g, b);

}
```

Comment: If Processing can load an external JAR and compile to Java 8, why not import a JAR that contains this code?

Comment: That is what I did for the twitter4j library. Im just still pretty new to programming. Could you point me in the direction of a JAR that would suffice? @Makoto

Answer (score 0):

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691175/changing-the-color-of-an-ellipse-using-hashtag-data-using-twitter4j-3-0-3), I showed you the syntax for doing this without Java 8 syntax:

```
int countTweets(ArrayList<String> statuses, String hashtag){
  int total = 0;
  for(String tweet : statuses){
    if(tweet.contains(hashtag)){
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```

You might be having difficulty because my examples used `String` values instead of `Status` values. You'll have to convert from `Status` instances to `String` values:

```
int countTweets(ArrayList<Status> statuses, String hashtag){
  int total = 0;
  for(Status tweet : statuses){
    if(tweet.getText().contains(hashtag)){
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```

Comment: You are seriously my savior these past few weeks; I cannot stress that enough. I cant believe it was that simple to convert string to status.

I added your modifications above, yet still get the int error. I assume that is from the lack of declared variables. What all do I need to declare, and do I just declare like `ArrayList<Status> tweets = new ArrayList<Status>();`

Im adding my current version as we speak @kevin-workman

Comment: @zack.gray.ou No problem. You might have better luck if you post a separate question for any subsequent issues, but it looks like you're declaring a function **inside** the setup() function. That's not valid syntax. More generally, now you've got **two** `countTweets()` functions- do you really need them both? Note that any code you get on here is to be used as an **example**, so you can't expect to just copy-paste answers and have them automatically work- the key is understanding what those answers are doing and then doing it with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple loop and a counter

```
public static int countTweets (String hashtag, List<Status> statuses) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < statuses.size() ; i++) {
        if (statuses.get(i).getText().contains(hashtag)) counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```